# RQT Multiple UI files

Tags: ros, python, rqt-gui, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a GUI for my robot using the rqt package and I want to be able to change the display when a button is clicked.

I've got it working with one ui file but can't seem to change the ui files over. I can make the ui disappear completely but I can't get the second one to appear.

Does anyone have any experience using rqt or any suggestions that might help?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120941/rqt-multiple-ui-files/) by [heyfred](https://answers.ros.org/users/1930/heyfred/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you have read the rqt Python plugin tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Python%20Plugin

There a UI file is loaded into self._widget which is then added to the main window.
What you want to achieve now is to switch the contents of this widget.
This is not anymore rqt specific, but a (Py)Qt question.
Also there are multiple solutions to this, I think this one found here is what you want:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625102/how-to-replace-a-widget-with-another-using-qt

The accepted answer tells you to use QStackedWidget with multiple widgets (each loaded from its own UI file) and switch between them:
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstackedwidget.html

In you case that would mean creating a QStackedWidget as self._widget and then adding you UI based widgets to it:

```
self._widget = QStackedWidget()
uiWidget1 = QWidget()
loadUi(ui_file1, uiWidget1)
self._widget.addWidget(uiWidget1)
uiWidget2 = QWidget()
loadUi(ui_file1, uiWidget2)
self._widget.addWidget(uiWidget2)
```

And then use the setCurrentIndex or setCurrentWidget methods of QStackedWidget to switch widgets in your callback function:

```
self._widget.setCurrentIndex(0)
self._widget.setCurrentWidget(uiWidget1)
```

---

Originally posted by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) with karma: 391 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0